# How to align input element in HTML?

Tags: html, css

[image: See the photo]

How can I do that?

My HTML code is

```
<p> <input type="text" name="Usuari" size="20" maxlength="60"/>
<p>CLAU:</label> <input type="text" name="Clau" size="20" maxlength="20" /></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="ACCÉS" /></p>-->
```

and my CSS code is

```
input {
    padding: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #008040;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border:1px dotted #004080;
}
```

Comment: you can use table for better alignment. no need of extra css .

Comment: Your code structure is poorly organised, why there is a `-->` at the end of the HTML code and where is the `<label>` opening tag,

Answer (score 2):

I would place "USUARI:" and "CLAU:" into div with class and give them fixed size.

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div class="hints">
    USUARI:
    </div>
    </div><input type="text" name="Usuari" size="20" maxlength="60"/>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="hints">CLAU:
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="Clau" size="20" maxlength="20" />
  </div>
</div>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="ACCÉS" />


<style>
input {
    padding: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #008040;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border:1px dotted #004080;
}

.hints
{
  width: 80px;
  float: left;
}
</style>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gm5wtw1e/

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do that.

You can either use flex or with just a plain table:

```html
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td><input name="name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sur Name:</td>
            <td><input name="surname"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

---

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: right;">Name:</td>
            <td><input name="name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sur Name:</td>
            <td><input name="surname"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
p{
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: right;
}
input {
  display: table-cell;
}
div.row{
    display:table-row;
}
```

```html
 <div class="row"><p> <input type="text" name="Usuari" size="20" maxlength="60"/></div>
    <div class="row"><p>CLAU:</label> <input type="text" name="Clau" size="20" maxlength="20" /></p></div>
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="ACCÉS" /></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
label
{
    display: block;
}

label span
{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<label>
    <span>USARI:</span>
    <input type="text" />
</label>
<label>
    <span>CLAU:</span>
    <input type="text" />
</label>
<label>
    <span></span>
    <input type="password" />
</label>
```

there are few error in your HTML code, you close the tag `label` but you never open it.
You should also wrap your fields in tag  and wrap your label in tag .
You don't need to open the tag

all the time, you can open it and close it at the beginning and at the end of the form. 
There is also a `-->` at the end of the code, I assume that's another mistake.

Here is my solution to your question:
**HTML**

```
<label>
    <span>USARI:</span>
    <input type="text" />
</label>
<label>
    <span>CLAU:</span>
    <input type="text" />
</label>
<label>
    <span></span>
    <input type="password" />
</label>
```

And here is my css code:
**CSS**

```
label
{
    display: block;
}

label span
{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100px;
}
```

You can now play with the CSS code in order to find the design that you like the most.